# Find string list inside text that have assigned to new values Python

Tags: python

I'm new to python (I started learning just last week). I'm trying to write a python script that does the following:
1- insert a text, e.g., 'Hello world!' (or larger text from a file)
2- create a list of all English alphabets (or alphabets of any other language), in which each letter is assigned to a new string value, e.g., the letter k = 'cv-'.
3- then write a statement like: if 'h' exists in the text, print out its assigned new string (from step 2).
4- the final output could be something like this: cv-cvv-cv (for each word in the text).

To summarize, I have 'a' (the text), 'b' (the list of the alphabets), 'c' (the new value of each alphabet), 'd' (the code, if statement or something similar), 'e', the output (something like cv-cvc-cv ..ete).

Run a, then using d, which goes though b and c, to give e.

Here is my attempt (without luck, of course). I'd appreciate any guidance and help.

```
text = 'a test'
letters = ['a', 't', 'e', 's']

if letters in text:
 print (a_val, t_val, e_val, s_val)
```

Comment: Well, what's `a_val` etc.? Don't see you defining them. Also, do you mean `charaters` when you say `alphabets`?

Comment: Thank you m02ph3u5 for your reply. a_val ...etc are meant to be put defined above as, e.g., a_val = 'cv'    # val means value here. (I might have deleted this from the code by mistake). Alphabets are characters yes.

Comment: This question is very unclear; I am not able to tell what you're trying to achieve. It would help if you gave actual inputs and outputs, rather than say the output is *"something like ..."*. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

```
    import string
    letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    print(letters)
    output: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',         'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    text = "hope this will help"
    splited_text = text.split(" ")
    print(splited_text)
    output: ['hope', 'this', 'will', 'help']
    your_dictionary = {} # use dictionary, it suits your problem

    for i in range(len(splited_text)):
        your_dictionary[letters[i]] = splited_text[i]

    print(your_dictionary)
    output: {'d': 'help', 'c': 'will', 'a': 'hope', 'b': 'this'}
```

You can sort the dictionary by keys then if you want.

```
    For k in your_dictionary.keys():
        If(your_dictionary[k] is in some_values):
            #do something
```